# Angular2: Passing multi-slot transcluded content to children components as parameters

Tags: angular, angularjs-ng-transclude

I am having and article component prefixed with b-...

```
<b-article>
```

and inside I have some custom elements

1. b-title
2. b-photo
3. b-summary

using like this:

```
<b-article-item>
    <b-title>My Article Title</b-title>
    <b-photo>http://placehold.it/1280X720</b-photo>
    <b-summary>some new content</b-summary>
</b-article-item>
```

so, if I wouldn't have some more components in the article-item (and no photo) then it would be fairly easy:

```
<div class="article">
    <h2><ng-content select="b-title"></ng-content></h2>
    <p class="summary"><ng-content select="b-summary"></ng-content></p>
</div>
```

but, already it get's complicated with the photo, where the src is as attribute

```
<div class="article">
    <img src="{{photo}}">
    <h2><ng-content select="b-title"></ng-content></h2>
    <p class="summary"><ng-content select="b-summary"></ng-content></p>
</div>
```

My structure is a bit more complicated, but doesn't make much difference in logic....

```
<div class="article">
    <b-thumbnail
        [photo] = "photo"
        [isResponsive] = "true"
    ></b-thumbnail>
    <b-excerpt
        [title]="title"
        [summary]="summary"
    ></b-excerpt>
</div>
```

HOW, do I get the b-photo's inner HTML as article-item's property...

Worth mentioning that b-photo, b-title and b-summary are not actual components, just custom tags (using CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA to allow them)

Any ideas?

I tried to put this in the article item constructor

```
constructor(private el:ElementRef){
    let ref = this.el.nativeElement;

    let photos = ref.getElementsByTagName('b-photo');

    if(photos.length > 0){
        this.photo = photos[0].innerHTML;
    }
}
```

Don't get an ewxpected result, the length is 0

Comment: Why don't you pass the value to an input like `<b-article-item [id]="http://placehold.it/1280X720">`?

Comment: well yes, I did that, but the demand from the bosses is to put them as an element :/

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I added my attempt

Comment: and what about the content and title? passing down to b-excerpt for example?

Comment: Something like that should be used. In my answer I show how you can get a specific element from the DOM to start the query (`getElementsByTagName()`) from there instead of the host element.

Comment: "passing down to b-excerpt for example? " I didn't understand that part of the question. How are `<div class="article"` and `<b-article-item>` related?

Comment: <div class="article"> is the template of <b-article-item> component

Comment: Then there shouldn't be anything to do. You assign the value you get from the query to a property and in the template bind to that property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely not how it should be done in Angular2 because it requires reading from the DOM and causes issues when server-side rendering and WebWorker features should be used.

This should work though:

```
<div class="article">
    <span #wrapper><ng-content select="b-photo"></ng-content></span>
</div>
```

```
export class BArticleItem {
  @ViewChild('wrapper') wrapper:ElementRef;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.photo = this.wrapper.nativeElement.querySelector('b-photo').innerHTML;
  }
}
```

Comment: but this would actually print the URL in the DOM, woudln't it? (<span #wrapper><ng-content select="b-photo"></ng-content></span>)